# why doesn't iOS Container replace work anymore?

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, replace, containers

At my work I work with Unity games published to iOS. For update testing and other testing purposes, I used to use the download container and replace container option in Xcode -> Window -> Devices and Simulators. But since recently, that option doesn't seem to work (well) anymore, specifically loading the containers back onto the device and I have no clue why this suddenly happened.

When I download a container I can see the stored information is saved in appdata->Library->Preferences->my_apps.plist. But when I try to replace containers, it silently refuses to work.

When looking at the device Console during replacement, I found the following leads:

> BUG IN CLIENT OF libsqlite3.dylib: database integrity compromised by
>   API violation: vnode unlinked while in use: ....

and

> Sandbox: mobile_house_arr(311) deny(1) file-write-create
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E0099BB7-3FC3-40EB-BE84-157BE681360B/Library/Caches/Snapshots/com.PaulChimp.FirstAppTest/08134EA5-0D8C-4228-9806-4E9788981A13@2x.ktx

Anyone else experiencing problems with replacing container files? Specifically with games made with Unity?

Comment: Check if the new container that your are uploading has some new file that could be refused from Xcode. I had a similar issue: the opening a database added some file that apparently was refused from Xcode. Removing them, the process completed successfully.

Comment: @Palleraccio Thank you for your reply. How do you know which files could be refused from Xcode? What kind of error message did you have?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't receive any kind of error. I have compared with a merge tool the downloaded container with the modified one, and I discovered which files were added. I know that this is not a "normal" way to find the error, but it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

When I ran into the same issue it turned out I had both databases (old and replacement) compiled into the project & was only loading one of the two. I believe the reason that error comes up is just that the files are in use when you try to make changes to the app's database.

I would recommend downloading the container using the Window > Devices & Simulators feature to see if you can find any obvious issues.

The app database location once downloaded is MYAPP.xcappdata (show package contents) > AppData > Library > Application Support.

I ended up downloading the container, removing the database I didn't need, and replacing the same container for the app.

Hope that's helpful! Best of luck!

Comment: thanks for helping. Did you delete all files with the Application Support folder? I only recognize ad network related folders in my container.

Comment: Sure thing Paul! I believe what's in that folder definitely depends on the app you are working on. In my case using CoreData to persist data I had .sqlite files (may show as 3 files for each database: yourname.sqlite, yourname.sqlite-shm, & yourname.sqlite-wal). The issue ended up being that I had multiple databases when I tried to replace one so I had to remove one of the yourname.sqlite files along with it's associated shm and wal. Deleting everything will probably not be a good idea.